# Define type of nested object only with string type value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a nested object with only string value like below:

```
let obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  foo2: "bar2",
  nestedFoo: {
    foo3: "bar3",
    anotherNested: {
      foo4: "bar4"
    }
  }
}
```

As I don't want to define exactly what keys inside,
so I try to create an interface type for it like below:

```
interface TestType {
  [key: string]: string|object
}
```

Now I have encountered two issues:

1. `nestedFoo` can pass the type checking, while `anotherNested` cannot pass.
2. While I try to use the values inside this nested object to other codes which required `string` type,
   it will fail the type checking.

How should I define the types of multi-nested keys & values without exactly defining the keys?

Answer (score 1):

To define the types for multi-nested keys and values without exactly defining the keys, you can use a recursive interface type in TypeScript. Here's an example of how you can define the type for your nested object:

```
interface NestedObjectType {
 [key: string]: string | NestedObjectType;
}
```

This interface type allows you to define an object with any number of string keys that have string or nested object values. The nested objects can also have any number of string keys that have string or nested object values, and so on recursively.

You can use this interface type to define your obj variable as follows:

```
let obj: NestedObjectType = {
  foo: "bar",
  foo2: "bar2",
  nestedFoo: {
    foo3: "bar3",
    anotherNested: {
      foo4: "bar4"
    }
  }
};
```

This type definition allows you to create an object with any number of nested levels and any number of string keys with string or nested object values, without having to explicitly define the keys at each level.